# Developing Drill Down Functionality on a Line Chart using Telerik RadHtmlChart

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, telerik

I am using RadHtmlChart control to display the absenteeism of several production plants on a daily basis. I am using the line series element and each plant has a  of its own.
Each production plant has many departments and each department has many designations. 
When I click on a particular plant I should be able to get the department level details belonging to that particular plant I selected.
Same goes for the getting the designations of a selected department (within the plant I selected) when I drill down further.

I used the following example : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/drilldownchart/defaultcs.aspx

This is for a column chart and it doesn't show me how I can identify the selected trend line.

```
string seriesName = RadHtmlChart1.PlotArea.Series[0].Name;
```

Instead of getting the name of the LineSeries at the 0th Index, I want the name of the selected LineSeries.

[image]

HTML Code:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HRTrends.aspx.cs" Inherits="HRTrends" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Title" runat="Server">       
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_PageTitle" runat="Server">        
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_PageSubTitle" runat="Server">        
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_BreadCrumb2" runat="Server">       
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_BreadCrumb3" runat="Server">        
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_PageContent" runat="Server">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
        <div class="portlet light ">
          <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption caption-md">
              <i class="icon-bar-chart theme-font-color hide"></i>
              <span class="caption-subject theme-font-color bold uppercase">Date Range</span>
              <span class="caption-helper"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p class="text-left">From Date:</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker_StartDate" runat="server" Width="90%"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_RadDatePicker_StartDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="RadDatePicker_StartDate" ValidationGroup="g1" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p class="text-left">To Date:</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker_EndDate" runat="server" Width="90%"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_RadDatePicker_EndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="RadDatePicker_EndDate" ValidationGroup="g1" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="Button_ApplyDateRange" runat="server" class="btn blue btn-block" validationgroup="g1" onserverclick="Button_ApplyDateRange_OnClick">Apply Date Range</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;" runat="server" id="Div_Error">
                <strong>Error!</strong>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_DateRange" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%--Absenteeism--%>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
          <div class="portlet light ">
            <div class="portlet-title">
              <div class="caption caption-md">
                <i class="icon-bar-chart theme-font-color hide"></i>
                <span class="caption-subject theme-font-color bold uppercase">Plantwise Absenteeism</span>
                <span class="caption-helper">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label_Absenteeism" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </span>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="codeBlock" runat="server">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  function OnClientSeriesClicked(sender, args) {
                    if ((args.get_seriesName() != "BEK1") && (args.get_seriesName() != "BEKA1") && (args.get_seriesName() != "BEN1") && (args.get_seriesName() != "BER1") && (args.get_seriesName() != "BERA1"))
                      $find("<%= RadAjaxManager_PlantSummary_Absenteeism.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest(args.get_category());
                  }
                </script>
              </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
              <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager_PlantSummary_Absenteeism_AjaxRequest">
                <AjaxSettings>
                  <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel_PlantSummary_Absenteeism"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                    </UpdatedControls>
                  </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                </AjaxSettings>
              </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
              <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" runat="server">
              </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
              <telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="100%" Skin="Bootstrap" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" OnClientSeriesClicked="OnClientSeriesClicked">
                <Legend>
                  <Appearance BackgroundColor="White" Position="Bottom">
                  </Appearance>
                </Legend>
                <PlotArea>
                  <Series>
                    <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEK" Name="BEK">
                      <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                      </Appearance>
                      <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                      <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                    </telerik:LineSeries>
                    <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEKA" Name="BEKA">
                      <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                      </Appearance>
                      <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                      <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                    </telerik:LineSeries>
                    <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEN" Name="BEN">
                      <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                      </Appearance>
                      <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                      <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                    </telerik:LineSeries>
                    <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BER" Name="BER">
                      <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                      </Appearance>
                      <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                      <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                    </telerik:LineSeries>
                    <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BERA" Name="BERA">
                      <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                      </Appearance>
                      <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                      <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                    </telerik:LineSeries>
                  </Series>
                  <XAxis DataLabelsField="Date">
                    <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="-45">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                    <TitleAppearance Text="Date">
                      <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                    </TitleAppearance>
                  </XAxis>
                  <YAxis>
                    <TitleAppearance Text="Absenteeism (%)">
                      <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                    </TitleAppearance>
                    <PlotBands>
                      <telerik:PlotBand From="5.8" To="6" Color="#CC0000" Alpha="90" />
                    </PlotBands>
                  </YAxis>
                </PlotArea>
              </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OperationsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SP_Get_VHRD_Designation_Wise_History_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
                </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END PORTLET-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <%--LTO--%>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
            <div class="portlet light ">
              <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption caption-md">
                  <i class="icon-bar-chart theme-font-color hide"></i>
                  <span class="caption-subject theme-font-color bold uppercase">Plantwise LTO</span>
                  <span class="caption-helper">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label_LTOP" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="portlet-body">
                <telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_LTOP" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="100%" Skin="Bootstrap" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_LTOP">
                  <Legend>
                    <Appearance BackgroundColor="White" Position="Bottom">
                    </Appearance>
                  </Legend>
                  <PlotArea>
                    <Series>
                      <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEK" Name="BEK">
                        <Appearance>
                          <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                        </Appearance>
                        <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                        <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                      </telerik:LineSeries>
                      <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEKA" Name="BEKA">
                        <Appearance>
                          <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                        </Appearance>
                        <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                        <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                      </telerik:LineSeries>
                      <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEN" Name="BEN">
                        <Appearance>
                          <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                        </Appearance>
                        <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                        <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                      </telerik:LineSeries>
                      <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BER" Name="BER">
                        <Appearance>
                          <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                        </Appearance>
                        <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                        <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                      </telerik:LineSeries>
                      <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BERA" Name="BERA">
                        <Appearance>
                          <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                        </Appearance>
                        <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                        <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                      </telerik:LineSeries>
                    </Series>
                    <XAxis DataLabelsField="Date">
                      <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="-45">
                      </LabelsAppearance>
                      <TitleAppearance Text="Date">
                        <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                      </TitleAppearance>
                    </XAxis>
                    <YAxis>
                      <TitleAppearance Text="LTO (%)">
                        <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                      </TitleAppearance>
                      <PlotBands>
                        <telerik:PlotBand From="2.9" To="3" Color="#CC0000" Alpha="190" />
                      </PlotBands>
                    </YAxis>
                  </PlotArea>
                </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_LTOP" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OperationsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SP_Get_VHRD_Designation_Wise_History_PlantSummary_LTO" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                  <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
                  </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PORTLET-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <%--Recruitment--%>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
              <div class="portlet light ">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                  <div class="caption caption-md">
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart theme-font-color hide"></i>
                    <span class="caption-subject theme-font-color bold uppercase">Plantwise Recruitments</span>
                    <span class="caption-helper">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label_Recruitment" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="actions">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                  <telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_Recruitment" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="100%" Skin="Bootstrap" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Recruitments">
                    <Legend>
                      <Appearance BackgroundColor="White" Position="Bottom">
                      </Appearance>
                    </Legend>
                    <PlotArea>
                      <Series>
                        <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEK" Name="BEK">
                          <Appearance>
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                          </Appearance>
                          <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                          <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                        <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEKA" Name="BEKA">
                          <Appearance>
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                          </Appearance>
                          <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                          <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                        <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEN" Name="BEN">
                          <Appearance>
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                          </Appearance>
                          <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                          <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                        <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BER" Name="BER">
                          <Appearance>
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                          </Appearance>
                          <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                          <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                        <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BERA" Name="BERA">
                          <Appearance>
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                          </Appearance>
                          <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                          <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                      </Series>
                      <XAxis DataLabelsField="Date">
                        <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="-45">
                        </LabelsAppearance>
                        <TitleAppearance Text="Date">
                          <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                        </TitleAppearance>
                      </XAxis>
                      <YAxis>
                        <TitleAppearance Text="Recruitment (Number of People)">
                          <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                        </TitleAppearance>
                      </YAxis>
                    </PlotArea>
                  </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
                  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Recruitments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OperationsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SP_Get_VHRD_Designation_Wise_History_PlantSummary_Recruitment" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                      <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
                      <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                  </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- END PORTLET-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <%--Actuals--%>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
                <div class="portlet light ">
                  <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption caption-md">
                      <i class="icon-bar-chart theme-font-color hide"></i>
                      <span class="caption-subject theme-font-color bold uppercase">Plantwise Actuals</span>
                      <span class="caption-helper">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label_Actuals" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="portlet-body">
                    <telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_Actuals" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="100%" Skin="Bootstrap" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Actuals">
                      <Legend>
                        <Appearance BackgroundColor="White" Position="Bottom">
                        </Appearance>
                      </Legend>
                      <PlotArea>
                        <Series>
                          <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEK" Name="BEK">
                            <Appearance>
                              <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                            </Appearance>
                            <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#3598DC" />
                            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                          </telerik:LineSeries>
                          <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEKA" Name="BEKA">
                            <Appearance>
                              <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                            </Appearance>
                            <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#1BBC9B" />
                            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                          </telerik:LineSeries>
                          <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BEN" Name="BEN">
                            <Appearance>
                              <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                            </Appearance>
                            <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#E26A6A" />
                            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                          </telerik:LineSeries>
                          <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BER" Name="BER">
                            <Appearance>
                              <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                            </Appearance>
                            <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#8877a9" />
                            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                          </telerik:LineSeries>
                          <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="BERA" Name="BERA">
                            <Appearance>
                              <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                            </Appearance>
                            <MarkersAppearance BackgroundColor="#F3C200" />
                            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
                          </telerik:LineSeries>
                        </Series>
                        <XAxis DataLabelsField="Date">
                          <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="-45">
                          </LabelsAppearance>
                          <TitleAppearance Text="Date">
                            <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                          </TitleAppearance>
                        </XAxis>
                        <YAxis>
                          <TitleAppearance Text="Actuals (Number of People)">
                            <TextStyle FontSize="12Px" />
                          </TitleAppearance>
                        </YAxis>
                      </PlotArea>
                    </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Actuals" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OperationsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SP_Get_VHRD_Designation_Wise_History_PlantSummary_Actuals" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                      <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
                      </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END PORTLET-->
              </div>
            </div>
  </asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;

public partial class HRTrends : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private DatabaseConnect db = new DatabaseConnect();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);

            DateTime startDateDT = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
            string startDate = startDateDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            DateTime endDate_DT = startDateDT.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
            string endDate = endDate_DT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            SetUpDates(startDate, endDate);            
        }
        Label_DateRange.Visible = false;
        Div_Error.Visible = false;
    }

    private void SetUpDates(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        string dateMessage = "From " + startDate + " To " + endDate;

        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Actuals.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = startDate;
        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Actuals.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = endDate;

        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Absenteeism.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = startDate;
        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Absenteeism.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = endDate;

        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_LTOP.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = startDate;
        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_LTOP.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = endDate;

        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Recruitments.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = startDate;
        SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Recruitments.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = endDate;

        Label_Actuals.Text = dateMessage;
        Label_Absenteeism.Text = dateMessage;
        Label_LTOP.Text = dateMessage;
        Label_Recruitment.Text = dateMessage;
    }

    protected void Button_ApplyDateRange_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            if (RadDatePicker_StartDate.SelectedDate <= RadDatePicker_EndDate.SelectedDate)
            {
                string startDate = RadDatePicker_StartDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string endDate = RadDatePicker_EndDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                SetUpDates(startDate, endDate);
            }
            else
            {
                Label_DateRange.Text = "You have selected an invalid date range. Please select a valid date range.";
                Label_DateRange.Visible = true;
                Div_Error.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void RadAjaxManager_PlantSummary_Absenteeism_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        string seriesName = RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_Absenteeism.PlotArea.Series[0].Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drill-down is initiated from the **client-side code**, so you can get the clicked series from the event arguments of the **seriesClick event** (your snippet already does that)

```
 function OnClientSeriesClicked(sender, args) {
                    alert(args.get_seriesName())
                  }
```

and the markup where it is set

```
<telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="RadHtmlChart_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="100%" Skin="Bootstrap" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PlantSummary_Absenteeism" OnClientSeriesClicked="OnClientSeriesClicked">
```